# Упростить условия в if

Tags: python, python-3.x, if

Как я могу обрезать строку if?

```py
string='да'
if string == 'Да.' or string == 'да.' or string == 'ДА' or string == 'Да' or string == 'да':
    print(string)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if string.lower() == 'да':
    print(string)
```

Если встречается точка, то

```
if string.lower() == 'да' or string.lower() == 'да.':
    print(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Упрощать, так упрощать :))

```
if string.rstrip('.').lower() == 'да':
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

if re.match(r'да\.?', string.lower()):
    print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

if re.match(r'да\.?', string, re.I):
    print(string)
```